# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to src.Profesor - Error when i try to read the file

Tags: java, arraylist, serialization, deserialization

The application when executed, creates an object by entering data by keyboard and adds them to the ArrayList  list. I get it to enter that object in the file but then when I run the application again, it does not return the contents of the file by console. He throws me an error in the cast

```
public static ArrayList<Profesor> obtenerArrayListDeArchivo(File profesores2) throws IOException {
        // para ver el contenido del fichero
        String ruta = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        ruta += "\\";// le añadimos el caracter \
        ArrayList<Profesor> lista = new ArrayList<Profesor>();

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(profesores2);
        ObjectInputStream entrada = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        try {
            while (true) {
                lista.add((Profesor) entrada.readObject());
            }
        } catch (EOFException ex) { //Con esto detectamos que estamos al final
            entrada.close();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        return lista;
    }
```

Main.java Class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        final Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        // leemos el directorio del programa, vamos uno atras y colgamos el fichero
        String ruta = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        // se queda con el path actual y le quitamos el último \directorio
        // ruta = ruta.substring(0, ruta.lastIndexOf("\\"));
        ruta += "\\";// le añadimos el caracter \

        // creamos y abrimos un fichero de texto globales1.txt para grabar el curso y el importe de hora extra
        File globales = new File(ruta + "globales1.txt");
        File profesores2 = new File(ruta + "profesores2.dat");


        ArrayList<Profesor> lista = new ArrayList<Profesor>();

        if (!globales.exists()) { 
            PrintWriter n = new PrintWriter(globales);
            double importe = 0;
            // asignar el atributo estatico curso
            String curso;
            System.out.print("Curso: ");
            curso = sc.nextLine();
            Profesor.setCurso(curso);
            System.out.print("Introduce el importe a pagar por cada hora extra: ");
            double pagoPorHoraExtra;
            importe = sc.nextDouble();
            Profesor.setPagoPorHoraExtra(importe);
            System.out.println();
            globales.createNewFile();
            n.println(curso + "#" + importe);
            n.close();
        } else {

            {
            try {
                lista=Funciones.obtenerArrayListDeArchivo(profesores2);
            } catch (IOException ex)
            {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
            Iterator it3 = lista.iterator();
            while(it3.hasNext())
            {
                System.out.println(it3.next());
            }

        }
```

Comment: Your error comes from 
`
lista.add((Profesor) entrada.readObject());
`
How are you saving your `Profesor` objects to file?  Can you please post that code as well as the `Profesor` class?

Comment: Method part1: public static void almacenarColPuntosEnArchivo(ArrayList<Profesor> lista, File profesores2) throws IOException {
        String ruta = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        // ruta = ruta.substring(0, ruta.lastIndexOf("\\"));
        ruta += "\\";
        File globales = new File(ruta + "globales1.txt");
        PrintWriter salida = new PrintWriter(globales);
        profesores2 = new File(ruta + "profesores2.dat");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(profesores2);
        ObjectOutputStream salidaProf = new ObjectOutputStream(fos); @ChocolateAndCheese

Comment: Method part 2: Profesor p = new Profesor();
 salida.println(p.getCurso() + "#" + p.getPagoPorHoraExtra());
 salida.close();
 int i;
        Iterator x = lista.iterator();
        while (x.hasNext()) {
            p = (Profesor) x.next();salidaProf.writeObject(p.getDni() + "-");
            salidaProf.writeObject(p.getNombre() + "-");
            salidaProf.writeObject(p.getSueldoBase() + "-"); for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
                salidaProf.writeObject(p.getHorasExtra(i) + "-");
            }salidaProf.writeObject(p.getTipoIRPF() + "\r\n"); }salidaProf.close();} @ChocolateAndCheese

Comment: Profesor.class Part 1: package src;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Profesor implements Serializable {private static String curso;
private static double pagoPorHoraExtra;
private String dni;
private String nombre;
    private double sueldoBase;
    private int[] horasExtra = new int[12];
    private double tipoIRPF;
    private int mes; public Profesor() {}
    public Profesor(String dni, String nombre, Double sueldoBase, int[] horasExtra, double tipoIRPF) {
this.dni = dni;
this.nombre = nombre; @ChocolateAndCheese

Comment: Profesor.class Part 2: this.sueldoBase = sueldoBase;
     this.horasExtra = horasExtra;
     this.tipoIRPF = tipoIRPF;
    } public void nuevoProfesor() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String dni, nombre;
        double sueldoBase;
        double tipoIRPF;

        System.out.print("Nif: ");
        dni = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Nombre: ");
        nombre = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Sueldo Base: ");
        sueldoBase = sc.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Tipo de IRPF: "); @ChocolateAndCheese

Comment: Profesor.class Part 3: tipoIRPF = sc.nextDouble();
        this.setDni(dni);
        this.setNombre(nombre);
        this.setSueldoBase(sueldoBase);
        this.setTipoIRPF(tipoIRPF);
        horasExtra = new int[12];
    } //then getters/setters @ChocolateAndCheese